# They pass comments, when I have disabled everything related to comments

Tags: comments, hacked

In my wordpress site I have comments disabled, but even so I am getting comments, I imagine that it is hacking. How can I block, override, disable everything related to comments from within a plugin?

Comment: Did you disable comments before creating posts? Discussion settings are set per post, while the setting in Settings > Discussion only applies to new posts.